# Reconfigure SharePoint to a new Sql Server box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server-2012, configuration-wizard

I am having SharePoint 2013 installed and configured on a Windows Server 2012 machine **without** Sql Server enterprise  edition[ I mean,inbuilt sql server express edition]. Now, I would like to configure/connect this SharePoint Server with another Sql Server Enterprise Edition which is installed on a different box.

Is this possible?  Can I configure this on the new Sql Server box after removing the existing sql server config? I want to change the SP config. from the single server stand alone installation to a  farm mode.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps can be taken to move the SQL Server on which SharePoint databases are stored:

1. Prepare the new SQL Server. Add the logins used for the SharePoint databases to the new instance. These can be copied from the old server with the same server roles. The DB permissions will be added when the DBs are migrated.
2. Shut down all of the SharePoint processes on the server.
3. Backup/detach the databases on the old SQL Server.
4. Restore/attach the databases on the new SQL Server. Check that the permissions have been correctly married up with the permissions created in step 1 for each database.
5. Create a SQL alias on the SharePoint server (use cliconfg.exe on the SharePoint server, enabled TCP/IP and create an alias whose name is the old SQL server/instance that points to the new SQL Server/instance).
6. Restart all of the SharePoint services or restart the SharePoint server.
7. Test.

See [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx) for further details.

Comment: Andy, thanks for the steps and detailed info.I am following the same and update here soon.